# Can't bind to "attribute" && "app-component" isn't a known element

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-pipe, angular-compiler, angular-input

I've a HUGE problem. The entire thing started with this: [Fix corrupted HTML file or decompile Angular Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692884/fix-corrupted-html-file-or-decompile-angular-component)

My PC suddently crashed and from that event it become worse every second. I get weird errors such as "'app-`component`' is not a known element" or "No pipe found with name 'async'" or even "Can't bind to '`attribute`' since it isn't a known property of 'app-`component`". I get this for many components.

*What I did:*
I immediately deleted the corrupted file I talked in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692884/fix-corrupted-html-file-or-decompile-angular-component) and I started to look at EVERY piece of code. EVERY error. But it seems all fine for me. It's fine even for Visual Studio Code, because it didn't trigger any error/problem to me as you can see here:
[VSC Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI4Zu.png)

I really don't know what should I do.

Here you can find the repository:
https://github.com/plungarini/alpha-project

Comment: Nobody here will clone your repository, that's beyond the scope of this site. However, if you have it all in a repository, have your tried deleting everything locally and tried cloning it again? If that doesn't help, have you tried going back commit by commit?

Comment: what heppend if you save corresponding ts file and module.ts file twice. same problem that i am facing right now, but after saving above files it runs perfectly

Comment: @RaviGajera I don't understand. What have you done?

Comment: See, I am not getting error at run time but whenever I edit my code sometimes it gives can't by ngIf , example-app is not a a know element and then I save( ctrl + s ) my corresponding ts file and module.ts file and the errors are gone. It worked because I have properly imported everything and not have any syntax error .  Same problem is occurred every day in my life in angular 10. But just save again

Comment: @RaviGajera I tried saving again, but it's not working for me. I even tried to start again the build, but nothing... it doesn't work

Comment: can you show me your code ?

Comment: Sure @RaviGajera, I have the github repo here: https://github.com/plungarini/alpha-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the whole thing. There was an error in the `dashboard-routing.module.ts`

I wasn't loading another module required to be correctly functional. I was loading instead a component.